# Extract the start date depending on data entry

Tags: sas

the following data ordered by id and date is given:

```
id type date
1  Y    01/01/2022
1  Y    09/01/2022
1  X    12/01/2022
2  Y    08/01/2022
2  X    09/01/2022
2  X    12/01/2022
```

I would like to set the start date according to the first entry of Y within each ID as follows:

```
id type date        Start
1  Y    01/01/2022  01/01/2022
1  Y    09/01/2022  01/01/2022
1  X    12/01/2022  01/01/2022
2  Y    08/01/2022  08/01/2022
2  X    09/01/2022  08/01/2022
2  X    12/01/2022  08/01/2022
```

Thank you very much in advance.

PP

I tried to use a do until loop to figure out the earliest event of 'Y' but i dont know how to link it with the according date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to RETAIN the new variable.  Normally new variables (those not coming from an input dataset) are reset to missing at the start of a new iteration of the data step.  But if you retain them then the value stays the same until changed by the program.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id date;
  if first.id then start=date ;
  retain start;
  format start mmddyy10.;
run;
```

To only select the first date that meets some other condition and have that value applied to records in the past will require more work.  It is clearer if you do it in two steps.

```
data start;
  set have;
  by id ;
  where type='Y';
  if first.id;
  keep id date;
  rename date=start;
run;
data want;
  merge have start;
  by id;
run;
```

To do it in a single data step you will to have the data step make two passes through the data.  You can use a double DO loop to do this. The first DO loop finds the start date. The second DO loop is used to re-read all of the observations for the group so they can be written out with the newly derived variable's value. RETAIN is not needed here as the value of START is only needed during the same iteration of the data step that creates it.

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id date;
    if type='Y' and missing(start) then start=date;
  end;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id date;
    output;
  end;
  format start mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of this function. But how to solve that problem when Y is not always the earliest entry?